# popup window in browser using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, popup

I am very new to VB but I'm loving it so far. I am trying to figure out how to create a popup window within a web application .aspx.vb using Visual Studio and Visual Basic Code. NOT C#.

My application has a bunch of different options (of course there is error checking that is not what I am asking) some of the options are optional. When they click the button I want a popup that asks "Are you sure this all you want?" This forces them to consider everything before the application commits it to global variables. Sorta like ordering a burger then being asked "would you like fries with that?". I would prefer that this popup is not a new tab on the browser, instead a new window so that I can choose the dimensions.

The popup should return a Boolean. This Boolean will be in an if statement that determines whether the button action should happen:

```
If popup() = True Then
'commit this purchase to global variables
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about javascript and client side scripting. All the confirmation dialogs should be shown in client side and after getting the result, the you need to call the servers side code, for example:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
    OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"/>
```

The code creates a button and if you click on button, the page will ask a question from user *'Are you sure?'* and if they click *'Ok'*, then the server side click handler of the button will execute. Otherwise, if they click on *'Cancel'*, page will not send the request to server.

Comment: That looks like HTML code. I don't know how to implement that. Is there a way to do this in the .aspx.vb visual basic coding file? I have been trying to use Response redirect but it opens an entirely new tab. I would like for it to only create a simple popup confirmation.

Comment: It's a server side tag which should be placed in .aspx. It's saying on clinet side, when user clicked on the button show a confirm box and if he clicked OK, run the code of the button click which you have in .aspx.vb otherwise don't run anything.

Comment: One problem, it displays the message, but it also says  "Local Host:##### says"  is there anyway to stop it from saying the Local Host message??